# Customize the android maps places?

Tags: android, customization, favorites

I want show the maps of my places, based on a selection of area like business,favorites, etc.
I am using the following intent for search and display the result in the maps in Android

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

When I click the maps place as favorites it shows that place in my places.

How can I divide the places based on category in Android?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the place api for getting the selection of area.

Step by step,

***How to get the list of nearest place of a location.***

**Step 1** : Go to API Console for obtaining the Place API

https://code.google.com/apis/console/

and select on services tab

[image: Service]

on the place service

[image]

now select API Access tab and get the API KEY

[image]

now you have a API key for getting place

---

**Now in programming**

***Step 2 ***  : first create a class named **Place.java**. This class is used to contain the property of place which are provided by Place api.

```
package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Place {
    private String id;
    private String icon;
    private String name;
    private String vicinity;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVicinity() {
        return vicinity;
    }

    public void setVicinity(String vicinity) {
        this.vicinity = vicinity;
    }

    static Place jsonToPontoReferencia(JSONObject pontoReferencia) {
        try {
            Place result = new Place();
            JSONObject geometry = (JSONObject) pontoReferencia.get("geometry");
            JSONObject location = (JSONObject) geometry.get("location");
            result.setLatitude((Double) location.get("lat"));
            result.setLongitude((Double) location.get("lng"));
            result.setIcon(pontoReferencia.getString("icon"));
            result.setName(pontoReferencia.getString("name"));
            result.setVicinity(pontoReferencia.getString("vicinity"));
            result.setId(pontoReferencia.getString("id"));
            return result;
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Place.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Place{" + "id=" + id + ", icon=" + icon + ", name=" + name + ", latitude=" + latitude + ", longitude=" + longitude + '}';
    }

}
```

Now create a class named **PlacesService**

```
package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;


public class PlacesService {

    private String API_KEY;

    public PlacesService(String apikey) {
        this.API_KEY = apikey;
    }

    public void setApiKey(String apikey) {
        this.API_KEY = apikey;
    }

    public List<Place> findPlaces(double latitude, double longitude,String placeSpacification) 
    {

        String urlString = makeUrl(latitude, longitude,placeSpacification);


        try {
            String json = getJSON(urlString);

            System.out.println(json);
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("results");


            ArrayList<Place> arrayList = new ArrayList<Place>();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    Place place = Place.jsonToPontoReferencia((JSONObject) array.get(i));

                    Log.v("Places Services ", ""+place);


                    arrayList.add(place);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            return arrayList;
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PlacesService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
//https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=28.632808,77.218276&radius=500&types=atm&sensor=false&key=your_api_key
    private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude,String place) {
         StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?");

        if (place.equals("")) {
                urlString.append("&location=");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
                urlString.append(",");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
                urlString.append("&radius=1000");
             //   urlString.append("&types="+place);
                urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        } else {
                urlString.append("&location=");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
                urlString.append(",");
                urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
                urlString.append("&radius=1000");
                urlString.append("&types="+place);
                urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        }


        return urlString.toString();
    }

    protected String getJSON(String url) {
        return getUrlContents(url);
    }

    private String getUrlContents(String theUrl) 
    {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return content.toString();
    }
}
```

Now create a new Activity where you want to get the list of nearest places.

/**
 * 
 */

```
    package com.android.code.GoogleMap.NearsetLandmark;

    import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.List;


    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.ListActivity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Point;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Location;
    import android.location.LocationListener;
    import android.location.LocationManager;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.ContextMenu;
    import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.android.code.R;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
    import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
    import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

    /**
     * @author dwivedi ji     * 
     *        */
    public class CheckInActivity extends ListActivity {

    private String[] placeName;
    private String[] imageUrl;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);




        new GetPlaces(this,getListView()).execute();
    }

    class GetPlaces extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
        Context context;
        private ListView listView;
        private ProgressDialog bar;
        public GetPlaces(Context context, ListView listView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.context = context;
            this.listView = listView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            bar.dismiss();
              this.listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, placeName));

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
              bar =  new ProgressDialog(context);
            bar.setIndeterminate(true);
            bar.setTitle("Loading");
            bar.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            findNearLocation();
            return null;
        }

    }
    public void findNearLocation()   {

        PlacesService service = new PlacesService("past your key");

       /* 
        Hear you should call the method find nearst place near to central park new delhi then we pass the lat and lang of central park. hear you can be pass you current location lat and lang.The third argument is used to set the specific place if you pass the atm the it will return the list of nearest atm list. if you want to get the every thing then you should be pass "" only   
       */


          List<Place> findPlaces = service.findPlaces(28.632808,77.218276,"atm");
                                                      // Hear third argument, we pass the atm for getting atm , if you pass the hospital then this method return list of hospital , If you pass nothing then it will return all landmark 

            placeName = new String[findPlaces.size()];
            imageUrl = new String[findPlaces.size()];

          for (int i = 0; i < findPlaces.size(); i++) {

              Place placeDetail = findPlaces.get(i);
              placeDetail.getIcon();

            System.out.println(  placeDetail.getName());
            placeName[i] =placeDetail.getName();

            imageUrl[i] =placeDetail.getIcon();

        }





    }


}
```

Comment: Hear i am pass a static value of lag and lat of location

Comment: hi Ashish here i am getting the list in first csreen how can display place in map when ever i click in the list place?

Comment: here i need to provide search maps in first screen then after i nedd to show the list

Comment: @user1365148 you should get the lat and long on click on the map. and pass the location in above code. this will provide the list of current location

Comment: @user1365148 show you should be update your question.Anyway i will give a full source code for that.. Cool dude!!!

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=streetdirectory.mobile&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInN0cmVldGRpcmVjdG9yeS5tb2JpbGUiXQ..

Comment: i need to develop the favorites ,business routs list based on maps place click  alert?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10879/discussion-between-user1365148-and-ashish-dwivedi)

Comment: here i want take any place in the map ?

Comment: @user1365148 Have a look this [project](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme)

Comment: i already referd that project but i didn't get the information regarding to my task

Comment: how can i add map search place to custom list-view in Android in the list we have four areas like places business,favorite ?

Comment: based on place click we can display the daialog box we want save this place to above place so that we can send that place to listview in Android ?

Comment: can u give any suggestion  to me